# cakephp 3 how to create new record from existing entity

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an entity with related data and I want save it in new record.

I Try it:

```
$newTour = $this->Tours->get($id, ['contain' => ['Cities', 'Tags']]);
$newTour->set('id', null);
$this->Tours->save($newTour);
```

But I saw this error:

> All primary key value(s) are needed for updating

what should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entities retrieved via `get()` or `find()` will be set as non-new, which causes them to end up in the update- instead of the insert-process when being saved.

If you want to insert them as new records, then you have to mark them as new, additionally to unsetting the primary key(s).

```
// ...
$newTour->isNew(true);
$newTour->unsetProperty('id');
// ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Updating Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data)**
- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\EntityTrait::isNew()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_isNew)**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$newTour->set('id', null);` unset the property using `$newTour->unsetProperty('id');`

Answer (score 0):

An important detail, when we have associated tables, loaded with the

`->contain()` option

, we need to do the same for each one recursively like:

```
 $newTour->isNew(true);
 $newTour->unsetProperty('id');
 $newTour->other_table->isNew(true);
 $newTour->other_table->unsetProperty('id');
```